# Esconder elemento quando selecionado por outro Select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, front-end

Tenho dois Select's que possuem a mesma lista de pessoas.
Quando eu selecionar a "Maria" do select A essa opção deve ser escondida do select B, visto que não podemos selecionar a mesma pessoa nos dois selects.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>
            Testemunha 1 :
        </label>
        <select select-normal data-placeholder="..." ng-model="notificacaoOrientativa.testemunha1"
                ng-options="obj as obj.pessoa.nome for obj in lstTestemunha">
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>
            Testemunha 2 :
        </label>
        <select select-normal data-placeholder="..." ng-model="notificacaoOrientativa.testemunha2" 
                ng-options="obj as obj.pessoa.nome for obj in lstTestemunha ">
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alguma sugestão de como implementar? OBS : Não posso 'excluir' as opções da Lista, apenas esconder no outro Select quando selecionado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode definir um ngChange para quando for alterado o valor do primeiro select.

E no controller você cria a função do ng-change para listar no segundo select.

```html
  <select select-normal data-placeholder="..." ng-model="notificacaoOrientativa.testemunha1"
                        ng-options="obj as obj.pessoa.nome for obj in lstTestemunha" ng-change="CarregarSegundoSelect(obj)>
                    <option></option>
                </select>
```

Comment: Não é possível fazer dessa forma sugerida, pois temos usuários que certamente irão selecionar primeiro o Select 2. Mas obrigado pela sugestão amigo

Comment: mas vc poderia fazer ng-change nos dois selects amigo, não digo para deletar o registro e sim apenas não mostrar, porque o usuário vai poder apenas escolher um registro certo? então vc recria a lista sem esse registro (apenas para exibição). e faz isso para os dois selects.

Comment: faz sentido, vou implementar e coloco aqui o resultado

Comment: resolvi o problema de uma maneira um pouco diferente, mas agradeço a sugestão meu brother

Answer (score 0):

Para quem estiver lendo aqui está a solução que encontrei. Não foi exatamente como eu queria inicialmente mas funcionou muito bem pro que eu queria.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>
            Testemunha 1 :
        </label>
        <select select-normal data-placeholder="..." ng-model="notificacaoOrientativa.testemunha1"
              ng-options="obj as obj.pessoa.nome for obj in lstTestemunha">
              <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>
            Testemunha 2 :
        </label>
        <select select-normal data-placeholder="..." ng-model="notificacaoOrientativa.testemunha2" ng-disabled="!notificacaoOrientativa.testemunha1"
                            ng-options="obj as obj.pessoa.nome for obj in lstTestemunha | filter: {pessoa:{ id: '!' + notificacaoOrientativa.testemunha1.pessoa.id }}">
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```